# Boost unit test failure detected in wrong test suite

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I'm learning how to use the Boost Test Library at the moment, and I can't seem to get test suites to work correctly. In the following code 'test_case_1' fails correctly but it's reported as being in the Master Test Suite instead of 'test_suite_1'.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
#define BOOST_AUTO_TEST_MAIN
#include <boost/test/auto_unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(test_suite_1);

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_case_1) {
    BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL(1, 2);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END();
```

edit:

Ovanes' answer led me to understand the suite hierarchy better - in this case test_suite_1 is a sub-suite of the root suite which by default is named 'Master Test Suite'. The default logging only shows the root suite, which isn't what I expected by I can deal with it :)

You can set the root suite name by defining BOOST_TEST_MODULE - so an alternative version of the above example which gives the expected error message is:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE test_suite_1
#define BOOST_AUTO_TEST_MAIN

#include <boost/test/auto_unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_case_1) {
    BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL(1, 2);
}
```

Comment: I'm glad I found this, but I'm completely gob-smacked at this behavior. Since you can only use `BOOST_TEST_MODULE` once, doesn't this mean there is essentially one suite per unit test executable? And that all test failures will be reported as members of this suite, with no sub-suite names? Surely I'm missing something here. Edit: formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you configure your logger to produce the report. For example passing to your example --log_level=all will result in the following output:

```
Running 1 test case...
Entering test suite "Master Test Suite"
Entering test suite "test_suite_1"
Entering test case "test_case_1"
d:/projects/cpp/test/main.cpp(9): fatal error in "test_case_1": critical check 1 == 2 failed [1 != 2]
Leaving test case "test_case_1"
Leaving test suite "test_suite_1"
Leaving test suite "Master Test Suite"

*** 1 failure detected in test suite "Master Test Suite"
```

Here is the link to the command line config options of [Boost Test Framework](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/reference.html).

Regards,
Ovanes

Answer (score 0):

Also, once you define BOOST_TEST_MODULE, you don't need to define BOOST_AUTO_TEST_MAIN